# How to see how many SalesForce licenses of each type are in use from a C# call to SFDC's web service?

Tags: c#, salesforce

We have a C# (winforms) application used for adding new starters to amongst other things AD, Exchange mailbox, sending emails to relevant people to say new starter arrived etc etc.

However, I'd like to extend this so that it also, where required, checks SFDC to see if there is a free licence available for their role.
If there IS then email SFDC admin to set them up (perhaps later do this in code as well).
If not, then notify different department of licence requirement.

Hoping to make a a C# call to the SFDC webservice.

I've looked through the documentation and can't find how to do this.

Comment: I need to do this programatically so that new users can only be added (or attempted to add) if there is a licence free.

Comment: "I need to do this programatically" if you can edit your question to describe how you are going to implement this "programatically" (what language, or in a macro/script, etc), you can flag to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open question or not, here's something I think might steer you in the right direction - the UserLicense object

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm

See also the Profile object, which has a "UserType" field that shows license info

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm

I've not dabbled with the API (yet!) but I'd imagine that it is possible to enumerate collections of Users and/or Profiles

Answer (score 0):

You just asked how to deal with a proprietary product unrelated to any of the topics this site covers (namely, anything programming-related). See https://stackoverflow.com/faq

You should contact their customer service, if their online docs are insufficient.

http://www.salesforce.com/services-training/customer-support/

Comment: Not strictly true - he asked on techniques to access a specific API via C#, which conceptually is more than covered by SO's remit.

Comment: @Rob: question was edited significantly since it was closed and this answer was posted, and the main part of the OP's question was/is finding out the proprietary API; the OP can flag/ask to reopen if they still need it answered